# Why does navbar button disappear in iOS10?

Tags: ios, swift4, navbar

The code to create button:

```
languageTopBarButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
languageTopBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGlobe"), for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.green, for: .normal)
languageTopBarButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(rightNavButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

let navBarHeight = navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
var rightButtonFrame = languageTopBarButton.frame
rightButtonFrame.size = CGSize(width: rightButtonFrame.width, height: navBarHeight!)
languageTopBarButton.frame = rightButtonFrame

let buttonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: languageTopBarButton)

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = buttonItem
```

the button is OK in iOS11, but it disappears in iOS10

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: "is OK in iOS10, but it disappears in iOS10" ?

Comment: @onnoweb oops mistaken thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to create a button. Works well on iOS10 and iOS11. I think the problem in your code is that you've set a wrong frame for your custom button.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setupBarButton()
}

private func setupBarButton() {
    let languageTopBarButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
    languageTopBarButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    languageTopBarButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "iconGlobe"), for: .normal)
    let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: languageTopBarButton)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
}
```